# i wonder about scott connection's phase shift like a 90 degrees

Tags: electrical

first of all it is necessary to refer this link.
https://circuitglobe.com/scott-t-transformer-connection.html 
In this link u can know scott connection and i wonder about V2t and V2m's phase difference.

something like wye-delta and delta-wye connection.

we can originally know wye-delta connection is step-down transformer and second side voltage phase is being to -30 degree. And also delta-wye connection is step-up transformer and second side voltage phase is being to +30 degree.

But the other side, we also can make wye-delta connection is step-up transformer if it get turn ratio like 1:2. So in this case maybe will be become +30 degree in second side voltage.

apply this principle in scott connection, how can work it?

case1) turn ration 1:2 - step up second side voltage's angle +90 degree?

case2) turn ration 2:1 - step down second side voltage's angle -90 degree?

if you have any information or homepage link, can you leave it for me?

As a result in this question's key point is this one.
https://circuitglobe.com/scott-t-transformer-connection.html 
In this web site, u can see scott connection and then i wonder about this phase shift. V2t and V2m have a phase difference of 90 degrees. And V2t is leading of V2m. But if we give another turn ratio like a step up or step down, is it possible to replace the position like V2t is lagging of V2m?

Comment: "Scott" should be capitalised as should the first word of each sentence. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: You asked virtually the same question yesterday: [i wonder about scott connection \[phase shift\]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496429/i-wonder-about-scott-connection-phase-shift). You also got what appears to be a good answer. Why are you basically reposting the same question especially as it has already been answered?

Comment: Yes right because i think this question is more clearly. So i uploaded again.